# El PreferenceManager en Android está obsoleto, ¿significa que no funciona en las últimas versiones?

Tags: android, kotlin

Hace uno o dos años, hice una aplicación para Android en Kotlin en la que guardaba cierta información usando el PreferenceManager. Hoy quise hacer una nueva versión de la app, y me he encontrado con que el PreferenceManager ha quedado obsoleto (Android Studio explica que está deprecated). En su lugar, la documentación de Android recomienda usar la PreferenceLibrary de AndroidX.

Después de buscar información al respecto, me han salido dos preguntas técnicas respecto al PreferenceManager y la librería Preference de AndroidX:

- ¿El hecho de que el PreferenceManager esté obsoleto implica que dejará de funcionar en el futuro?
- Por otro lado, ¿es posible usar las librerías de AndroidX (como la Preference) en versiones antiguas de Android (como Android 5)?

Muchísimas gracias por su ayuda, y ojalá puedan contestar mis preguntas, porque ando algo perdido y no entiendo muy bien qué implica que algo quede obsoleto (deprecated).

Comment: Que esté obsoleto significa que es recomendable usar otras alternativas por algún motivo. Ya sea por seguridad, privacidad u otro. Claro que puedes seguir usándolo.

Comment: Si vas a la documentación de [PreferenceManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager) dice que a partir de la API 29 uses la librería Preference de AndroidX para un comportamiento consistente en todos los dispositivos. En la documentación de [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) describe que es una biblioteca que ofrece compatibilidad con versiones anteriores y está para reemplazar a la vieja biblioteca de compatibilidad. Respondiendo a tus dos preguntas, lo correcto es usar la nueva librería. No te preocupes por la compatibilidad.

Comment: Si lo continuas usando en algún momento deberás de migrar a Android X, lo ideal es migrar ahora mismo. Revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Saludos Mateo, gracias por tu información. Es lo que necesitaba.

Comment: Por cierto, @Elenasys, tengo una duda: ¿qué puedo hacer para mejorar la pregunta? No la considero basada en opiniones porque son dos dudas objetivas respecto a la programación. Muchas gracias también, y ojalá puedas ayudarme a mejorar.

Comment: preguntas cuando usar una u otra ya que tienes duda en cuanto a las recomendaciones que encontraste, si deseas una opinión o recomendación puedes realizarlo en [chat] , lo correcto sería preguntar cual es el problema que se tiene al implementar PreferenceManager  o PreferenceLibrary ?, saludos.

Comment: Entiendo, ¡gracias por responder! A la próxima intentaré hacerlo mejor.